# Error Handler not catching Errors in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

On my venture in learning PowerShell, I have hit into another issue which I would like to get your help in this.

I have a code below inside a `try-catch` but when an error occurs inside the `try` block it does not seem to send it to `catch` block.

The Code:

```
try{
        if ($isFileAvailable -gt 0){
             $hashArgumentWithAttachment = @{
                From = $From
                To = $To
                Subject = $Subject
                Body = $Body
                SmtpServer = $SMTPServer
                Port = $SMTPPort
                UseSsl = $true
                Credential = $smtpCredential 
                Attachments = $filePath
            }

            Send-MailMessage @hashArgumentWithAttachment
        }
        Else {
            $hashArgumentWithOutAttachment = @{
                From = $From
                To = $To
                Subject = $Subject
                Body = $Body
                SmtpServer = $SMTPServer
                Port = $SMTPPort
                UseSsl = $true
                Credential = $smtpCredential 
            }

            Send-MailMessage @hashArgumentWithoutAttachment
        }
        Write-Output "Emailed"
        break
    }catch { 
        Write-Output "Error Occured, No of Attempts So far: " + $attempts.ToString()
    }
```

On an instance where there is a Server connectivity error I expect to hit the catch block but instead it throws an error like this:

[image]

Comment: Try adding the erroraction to the cmdlet: Send-MailMessage -ErrorAction Stop

Comment: @BernardMoeskops thank you for your response. I think `ErrorAction` while solve my problem. Let me do some further testing and will have your answer confirmed! Thank you again!

Comment: @BernardMoeskops My tests seems to work well. Thank You very much. Mention it in the Answer section and I will have it confirmed in no time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add ErrrorAction to the CMDLet:

```
Send-MailMessage @hashArgumentWithoutAttachment -ErrorAction Stop
```

Cheers!